# I cannot resize big resolution image in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, image

I am using this library https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper

I have an image that has a 15k x 8k dimension, which I can normal resize with an **img** component.

However, using the library's  component I cannot resize it. I tried the 3 following resizing methods.

-I tried to resize the parent div with width and height.

`<ImageMapper src={sampleIMG} map={MAP} imgWidth={200} natural />` and
 `<ImageMapper src={sampleIMG} map={MAP} imgWidth={200} natural />`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with `width` (Image width, in function you will get image reference object) or `parentWidth` (parent max width for responsive) ?

```
      <ImageMapper 
        src={URL} 
        map={MAP}
        width={props.width} // dynamic width
        height={props.height} // dynamic height
        imgWidth={props.imgWidth} // dynamic imgWidth
        natural={props.natural} // dynamic natural
        responsive={props.responsive} // dynamic responsive
        parentWidth={props.parentWidth} // dynamic parentWidth
   />
```

Comment: its shows wrong coordinates when I make natural props true,  and when false. no on hover highlights are making